# casl integration with angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, casl

I am trying to integrate CASL in my angular app. I don't understand how to integrate it.

```js
// Login Conponent

ngOnInit() {
  var jsonBody = {};
  jsonBody['email'] = 'peter@klaven';
  jsonBody['password'] = 'cityslicka';

  this._session.login(jsonBody)
}

//session.ts

import { Ability } from '@casl/ability'
 
export class Session {
  private token: string
 
  constructor(private ability: Ability) {}
 
  login(jsonBody) {
    return fetch('https://reqres.in/api/login', { method: 'POST', body:  JSON.stringify(jsonBody) })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(session => {
        this.ability.update(session.rules)
        this.token = session.token
       })
  }
 
  logout() {
    this.token = null
    this.ability.update([{ actions: 'read', subject: 'all' }])
  }
}

// Ability.ts

import { AbilityBuilder } from '@casl/ability';
 
export const ability = AbilityBuilder.define(can => {
  can('read', 'all')
})

// can pipe

import { CanPipe } from '@casl/angular'
import { Pipe } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: 'can' })
export class MyCanPipe extends CanPipe {}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="'Post' | can: 'create'">
  <a (click)="createPost()">Add Post</a>
</div>
```

in the above code, I have added all the required file code that ability, session, can pipe, HTML code etc. I have followed all the steps given by the library 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/@casl/angular'. I am getting 'Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Session: (?).
' this error. I don't understand what is wrong with it & how to integrate this package. please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please show the code which adds AbilityModule and Session into Angular ?

Comment: There is a working example: https://github.com/stalniy/casl-angular-example and article now: https://medium.com/@sergiy.stotskiy/managing-user-permissions-in-angular-application-504c83752f83

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/stalniy/casl-examples/tree/master/packages/angular-todo

go througbh this example for angular and other technology
Example is very simple and enought to understand things

You can add Todo task with different assignee, but you can only delete and update task wich is assigned only as Me and admin role.